# PHP Получить имя файла , у которого присутствует расширение(.txt)

Tags: php

Подскажите, как можно узнать имя файла в текущей папке, у которого есть расширение .txt  ?

Comment: glob("/путь/к/папке/*.txt")

Comment: Хм... спасибо, лучше моего варианта )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
     if(stristr($fileinfo->getBasename(), '.txt') == TRUE) {
        echo $fileinfo->getBasename();
      } 
    }
}
```

Проверяем в текущей папке все файлы которые содержат .txt и выводим его ПОЛНОЕ название

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: `stristr($fileinfo->getBasename(), '.txt')` также вернет тру для файла например `file.txt.pdf.doc` Поэтому надо использовать `fileinfo->getExtension()`